# Calculo de distancia entre pontos geograficos com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

Eu tentei rodar na internet, Mas a unica forma que cheguei a encontra é o calculo da distancia entre dois pontos (longitude ,latitude).
No meu caso, eu tenho uma lista de posições(longitude e latitude) das lojas e tambem a posição (longitude e latitude) do usario(cliente). Eu já consegui jogar tudo todos esses dados Numa pagina .agora falta como fazer para poder calcular a ditancia do usario para cada um dessas lojas.

Quem puder ajudar, já já agradeço

Answer (score -1):

Existem algumas maneiras de calcular a distância entre dois pontos geográficos, sendo a mais comum a utilização da fórmula de Haversine, que permite calcular a distância entre dois pontos em uma esfera a partir de suas longitudes e latitudes.

Veja abaixo um exemplo de como calcular a distância entre dois pontos utilizando a fórmula de Haversine:

**d = 2 * R * asin(sqrt(sin^2((lat2 - lat1)/2) + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin^2((lon2 - lon1)/2)))**

onde:

d é a distância entre os dois pontos, em quilômetros;
R é o raio da Terra, que é aproximadamente 6371 km;
lat1 e lon1 são as coordenadas geográficas do primeiro ponto, em radianos;
lat2 e lon2 são as coordenadas geográficas do segundo ponto, em radianos.

Para calcular a distância entre todas as lojas e o usuário, basta iterar por cada loja e calcular a distância utilizando a fórmula acima. É importante lembrar de converter as coordenadas geográficas para radianos antes de utilizar a fórmula, pois ela trabalha com essa unidade de medida.

Exemplo de código em PHP:

```
    // Declara as constantes
    const EARTH_RADIUS = 6371; // raio da Terra, em km
    
    // Recebe as coordenadas dos dois pontos
    $lat1 = -23.550520;
    $lng1 = -46.633309;
    $lat2 = -23.543247;
    $lng2 = -46.644391;
    
    // Converte as coordenadas para radianos
    $lat1 = deg2rad($lat1);
    $lng1 = deg2rad($lng1);
    $lat2 = deg2rad($lat2);
    $lng2 = deg2rad($lng2);
    
    // Calcula a distância entre os dois pontos
    $deltaLat = $lat2 - $lat1;
    $deltaLng = $lng2 - $lng1;
    
    $a = sin($deltaLat/2) * sin($deltaLat/2) +
         cos($lat1) * cos($lat2) *
         sin($deltaLng/2) * sin($deltaLng/2);
    
    $c = 2 * atan2(sqrt($a), sqrt(1-$a));
    
    $distance = EARTH_RADIUS * $c;
    
    echo "A distância entre os dois pontos é de $distance km";
```

Espero que isso ajude!